# How to get audio of presenter while doing screenshare in WebRTC?

Tags: webrtc

We are building a WebRTC video call web app with screenshare. When screenshare is on, the presenter's audio is not coming through. Audio for screenshare video source has been set to false, but it still does not work. Any solutions please?

Comment: `false` means you don't want audio.

Comment: we tried setting it to true as well.

Answer (score 0):

For Chrome you can create 2 streams, one for audio (with cam) and another for desktop. 
We found, that for screenshare video source, audio can be added just in FireFox... 
We are waiting for Chrome support of this mode.